# Run selenium node using batch file in windows

Tags: batch-file, selenium

I am trying to run selenium node with batch file, there is no errors but not work at all, here is my code:

NOTE: The batch file gets the ip address as an argument

```
    cd c:\
    cls
    set s1=http://
    set s2=%1
    set s3=:1111/grid/register
    SET IP_ADRESS = %s1%%s2%%s3%

    echo %IP_ADRESS%
    pause
    java -jar C:\selenium_standalone\selenium-server.jar -role node -hub %IP_ADRESS%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces before and after the `=` from `SET IP_ADRESS = %s1%%s2%%s3%`, and it will work.

```
SET IP_ADRESS=%s1%%s2%%s3%
```